# Azure EventHub - get information about last commited offset

Tags: python, azure, rest, apache-kafka

Is there any way to get information of last commited offset for Azure EventHubs per selected groupid?
We need it for automatic tests for our solution that we currently migrating from mapr streams to Azure EventHub.
Our current tests flow (we are using Python libraries + rest api calls):

1. Send messages to queue (save partitions/offsets of sent messages)
2. Wait until all messages were consumed (we are getting info about current commited offsets for groupid used by job that we are testing; if offsets are commited its mean that job consumed our messages and we can go to next step)
3. Validate job output (another queue or db)

I already checked eventhub rest api but non of requests is returning that info. Also tried to get this info from EventHubConsumerClient (python) but same, without success.

I can get this info using confluent_kafka consumer client:

```
topic = topics[0]
consumer = Consumer(conf)
consumer.subscribe(topics)
metadata1 = consumer.list_topics(topic, timeout=10)
print(metadata1.topics)
partitions = [confluent_kafka.TopicPartition(topic, p) for p in metadata1.topics[topic].partitions]
print(partitions)
committed = consumer.committed(partitions, timeout=60)
print('partition: {}, committed offset: {}'.format(0, committed[0].offset))
print('partition: {}, committed offset: {}'.format(1, committed[1].offset))
print('partition: {}, committed offset: {}'.format(2, committed[2].offset))
consumer.close()
```

output:

```
partition: 0, committed offset: 16
partition: 1, committed offset: 34
partition: 2, committed offset: 8
```

but it crashing our job (looks like 2 consumers with same groupid are not allowed in same time).

Any ideas ?

In current tests (solution based on mapr streams) we are using this:
https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/70/ReferenceGuide/stream_cursor_list.html
and looking for something giving similar functionality..